# MVC Request.Files always empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, empty-list

I am having a really frustrating problem concerning the file upload control of HTML in MVC.

I have read about many solutions but none seem to work. I believe I do not have any missing info needed:

Form

```
<form id="formdata" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Forms/ProposalForm/1">
```

File upload control

```
<input type="file" multiple="" name="fileupload" />
```

I am using **.NET 3.5 and MVC2**. Other info is that, I am using a MasterPage as well as PartialControls (my form tag is inside the main View and my file input tag is inside the Partial View), but I am not sure if it affects it.

Comment: Post your View and you Controller.

Comment: Sorry nevermind, I figured out the answer myself, I posted it

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem myself.

I was submitting the form via jQuery something like $('#formdata').submit(); ... Turns out it was overwriting the enctype="multipart/form-data" by itself and submitting it as normally.

What I did was just to use plain old javascript (document.getElementById ..) to submit the form and it was fixed.

Comment: To upload a file it needs a full postback... not an Ajax one.